# How to display a Grideview information in software stimulsoft reporting?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stimulsoft

I want to create a table report information I use Stimulsoft software for reporting. I have many databases. In C # I have a GridView that I want to print the information inside of that GridView in my report but in Stimulsoft software, I don't know what to write in the data source in Stimulsoft I used the following code in C #:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
            table.Columns.Add(column.Name, typeof(string));
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            table.Rows.Add();
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                table.Rows[i][j] = dataGridView1[j, i].Value;
            }
        }
        DataSet Ds = new DataSet("DaneBandiTable");
        Ds.Tables.Add(table);

        StiReport report = new StiReport();
        report.Load(Application.StartupPath+@"\DaneBandiReport.mrt");
        report.RegData(table);
        //report.Design();
        report.Compile();
        report.Show();
    }
```

and my connection string :

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=" + databasename + ";Integrated Security=True");

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM DaneBandiTable", conn);
```